# Force isc-dhcpd to disregard client hostname in ddns updates

Tags: networking, dhcp, linux-networking, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have the following configuration of isc-dhcpd-4.3.1:

```
ignore client-updates;
ddns-update-style interim;
subnet 192.168.128.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

    use-host-decl-names on;
    update-static-leases on;

    key "rndc-key" {
            algorithm hmac-md5;
            secret "redacted";
    };
    zone example.com. {
            primary 127.0.0.1;
            key rndc-key;
    }
    zone 128.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
            primary 127.0.0.1;
            key rndc-key;
    }

    authoritative;
    range 192.168.128.32 192.168.128.63;

    next-server 192.168.128.1;

    option domain-name "example.com";
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.128.1;

    group {
            host test {
                    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
            }
    }}
```

What is happening is that despite the `ignore client-updates`, the ddns entries created are defaulting to the server's hostname at the time of the dhcp query, ie: `localhost.example.com`. The server, after it's initial dhcp query correctly sets its hostname to `test.example.com` and a `service networking restart` will then have the correct DDNS entries created.

I am at a complete loss as to why dhcpd is listening to the client sending a hostname of `localhost` despite the setting telling it not to.

Some assistance with this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and came up with the solution to add `ddns-hostname` to the host config. 
`use-host-decl-names` neither `ignore client-updates` change any behavior of the dhcpd.

The following function worked finally, even tho clients still tried to update the dns with their hostname:

```
host client.foo.bar {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:AA;
        fixed-address 192.168.42.2;
        ddns-hostname "foo";
        }
```

If you find a better solution please let me know!